# Proving $∠CAD = 90◦$

Tags: geometry

In a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$, let the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at
$X$. Let the circumcircles of triangles $AXD$ and $BXC$ intersect again at $Y$.
If $X$ is the incentre of triangle $ABY$ , show that $∠CAD = 90^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we show that point $Y$ lies on the edges $CD$. Look at quadrilateral $XCYD$. We will prove that $\angle \, CYD = 180^{\circ}$.

[image]

1. $\angle\, XDY = \angle \, XAY = \alpha$ as inscribed in a circle.
2. $\angle \, BAC = \angle \, BAX = \angle \, XAY = \alpha$ since $AC$ passes through the incenter $X$ of triangle $ABY$ and therefore $AC$ is the interior angle bisector of angle $\angle \, BAY$.
3. $\angle \, XDC = \angle \, BDC = \angle \, BAC = \alpha$ as inscribed in a circle.
4. Hence $\angle \, XDC = \angle \, XDY = \alpha$.
5. Analogously, $\angle \, XCD = \angle \, XCY = \beta$.
6. In triangle $CDX$ angles sum up to $180^{\circ}$ so  $$180^{\circ} = \angle \, CXD + \angle \, XCD + \angle \, XDC = \angle \, CXD + \alpha + \beta$$ and thus $\angle \, CXD = 180^{\circ} - \alpha - \beta$.
7. In quadrilateral $XCDY$ angles sum up to $360^{\circ}$ so $$360^{\circ} = \angle \, CXD + \angle \, XCY + \angle \, XDY + \angle \, CYD  = \angle \, CXD + \alpha + \beta + \angle \, CYD = $$ $$= 180^{\circ} +  \angle \, CYD $$ therefore $\angle \, CYD = 180^{\circ}$ and thus $Y$ lies on $CD$.

Now, we are ready to prove that $\angle \, CAD = 90^{\circ}$.

8. $\angle \, AXD = \angle \, BXC$ since $X$ is the intersection point of $AC$ and $BD$.
9. $\angle \, AYD = \angle \, AXD$ and $\angle \, BYC = \angle \, BXC$ as inscribed in corresponding circles. Hence $\angle \, AYD = \angle \, BYC$
10. $\angle \, XYA = \angle \, XYB$ since $YX$ is angle bisector of $\angle \, AYC$. Hence
    $$\angle \, XYD = \angle \, XYA + \angle \, AYD = \angle \, XYB + \angle \, BYC = \angle \, XYC$$
11. But $180^{\circ} = \angle \, XYD + \angle \, XYC = 2 \, \angle \, XYD $ so $\angle \, XYD = 90^{\circ}$.
12. As quadrilateral $AXYD$ is inscribed in a circle, $180^{\circ} = \angle \, XAD + \angle \, XYD = \angle \, XAD + 90^{\circ}$ so $\angle \, XAD = 90^{\circ}$.
13. $X \in AC$ so $\angle \, CAD = \angle \, XAD = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Off topic: Nice answer!, but what program or appl. you use for draw this?? Thanks

Comment: @MathUser I use Inkscape. It is not very fancy, but I am very comfortable with it. A matter of habit I would say.